# How to upload video to vimeo through swift

Tags: alamofire, vimeo, vimeo-api

I need to upload a video file to vimeo from my ios app.
Vimeo's iOS library is deprecated, so I'm trying to upload a video using the api on the Vimeo developer site.
https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos
I'm using the resumable approach.
There are 3 steps in total. Step 1 was successful and step 2 is still failing.
Here's the method I tried in step 2:

```
private func uploadVideoToVimeo(uploadLink:String) {
    
    let urlString   = uploadLink
    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [ "Tus-Resumable":"1.0.0",
                                 "Upload-Offset": "0",
                                 "Content-Type": "application/offset+octet-stream",
                                 "Accept":"application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.4"]

    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: urlString)!)
    request.headers = headers
    request.method = .patch
    
    AF.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        let timestamp = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: self.videoLocalURL, options:.mappedIfSafe)
            print("data size :\(data)")
            multipartFormData.append(data, withName: "\(timestamp)")
        } catch {}
    }, with: request).responseString { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let data):
            print("esponse :\(response)")
        case let .failure(error):
            print("ERROR :\(error)")
        }
    }
     
    
}
```

When I do this, the response is “missing or invalid Content-Type header”.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Alamofire, and Apple's network frameworks in general, don't support the TUS protocol for uploads. You either need to implement that manually and upload a stream, or switch to using the form-based approach outlined in the Vimeo docs.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Where can I get a swift example?